# Which groups have only real representations?

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, representation-theory

An irreducible representation $\rho$ (with character $\chi$) of a finite group is called a "real" representation if its Frobenius-Schur indicator is 1:
$$\frac{1}{\lvert G \rvert} \sum_{g \in G} \chi\left(g^2\right) = 1$$
Alternatively, it is real if it has a symmetric bilinear, $G$-equivariant form.

Finite groups can have real, quaternionic and complex representations. Some groups like the symmetric group have only real representations.

*Which groups have only real representations?*

Comment: @ladisch, yes, thank you!

Comment: You probably know that all irreducible characters are real-*valued* iff every group element is conjugate to its inverse. But this means just that all irreps are real or quaternionic. I don't know a characterization of groups with only irreps of real type. Maybe related: http://mathoverflow.net/q/109045/10266

Comment: @ladisch, I didn't know that, but that's also valuable. That would mean that in such a group, every representation is self-dual, right?

Comment: Yes, then every representation is self-dual.

Comment: Thanks for linking the question. An [article linked therein](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/002186937690096X) says that at least in the 70's, this was not so clear. [Another linked article](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1210.3790v1.pdf) calls groups with my desired property "totally orthogonal", and apparently this is ongoing research.

Answer (score 5):

The correct term for this kind of groups is called "*totally orthogonal*" (e.g. orthogonal groups have this property). It was coined in [this article](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0022404988900369) by Wang and Grove, together with many propositions about their structure.
For example, it contains:

**Theorem 3.3** If $G$ is totally orthogonal, it is generated by involutions.